# Eclipse marketspace issue

Tags: java, eclipse

MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.20: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and show what you've tried so far to solve the issue (e.g. any research). Note that we're sacrificing our time to help so it needs be valued by not just dumping errors into our laps and expecting us to solve them.

Comment: It looks like you are using Eclipse 2021-06 on a Windows 32 bit machine. As far as I know, that version of Eclipse is 64 bit.